# Adding the three highest numbers out of four randomly generated numbers

Tags: python-2.7

I'm am currently randomly generating four numbers. With those four numbers I want to take the highest three and add them together.

Using the variables r1, r2, r3, and r4 how would I go about doing this?

Comment: `sum(sorted([r1, r2, r3, r4])[-3:])`?

Answer (score -2):

// in C++

```
   float f1 = 1, f2 = 2, f3 = 3, f4 = 4;
   float sum = f1 + f2 + f3 + f4;
   sum -= min(f1, min(f2,min(f3, f4);
   cout << "Answer = " << sum << endl;
```

Answer = 9